# any linear function an + b is O(n^2) CLRS

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, clrs

In 3rd edition of CLRS specifically section 3.1 (page 47 in my book) they say

> when a > 0, any linear function an + b is in O(n^2), which is easily verified by taking c = a + |b| and n0 = max(1,-b/a).

where n0 is the value such that when n >= n0 we could show that an + b <= cn^2 in a proof of the above.

1. I tried to verify this but I couldn't get very far :(
2. How did they choose these values of c and n0?  I know that the only thing that matters is that there exists such a c and n0 such that the above is true to prove that an + b is O(n^2) but I wonder how did they choose specifically those values of c and n0? They don't seem arbitrary, its as if they applied some technique I have never seen before to obtain them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the simple case where `a` and `b` are both positive. What the authors are trying to do is to create a value where the quadratic function dominates the linear function for n >= 1. *That's it. They're just trying to create a general solution to show where the right parabola dominates any line.*

So for `n=1`, the value of the linear function (i.e. `l(n) = an + b`) will be `a+b` when `n=1`. A dominating quadratic without any linear sub-functions (i.e. `q(n) = c * n^2`) would dominate the linear function, `l(n)` at `n=1` if we choose `c = a + b`. So, `q(n) = (a+b)n^2` dominates `l(n) = an + b` when `n>=1`, assuming `a` and `b` are both positive. You can check out examples for yourself for [plotting `30x^2` and `10x + 20` on Densmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pnbrikxdqw).

It's a bit trickier when `b` is negative, but the positive case is basically the point.